# Access partial stdout and stderr when create_subprocess_shell() times out

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to use asyncio's [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) (e.g. `create_subprocess_shell`) instead of the usual ordinary subprocess module and I can't figure out how to access stdout and err when the task times out:

In the non-asyncio subprocess module the `run()` method or `Popen.communicate()` have a timeout argument and when the exception is raised you can still access `stdout` or `stderr` attributes of the process and see the partial outputs. This is not the case for asyncio's `communicate()` method and the [docs suggest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#interacting-with-subprocesses) suggest using `wait_for` or `wait` for a timeout. I can't find a way to access stdout/err with either `wait_for`, which cancels the task, or `wait`, which lets the task run but raises an exception. I'm aware of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639984/python3-asyncio-wait-for-communicate-with-timeout-how-to-get-partial-resul) from 6 years ago but the answers didn't work for me and I was wondering if an easier solution is now available.

The setup is something like this:

```py
proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
    cmd, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
)

task = asyncio.create_task(proc.communicate())
try:
    await asyncio.wait_for(task, timeout=timeout_secs)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    # What do I do here?
```

or:

```py
task = asyncio.create_task(proc.communicate())
done, expired = await asyncio.wait([task], timeout=timeout_secs)

if done:
    stdout, stderr = done.pop().result()
    return stdout, stderr
else:
    # What do I do here?
```